# c++ assign a reference to property in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, variable-assignment

I need to pass a database connection to a new object instance. However, the following code is not working as wanted.

```
class child {
  public:
    db_connection Con;
    child(db_connection& Con);
};

child::child(db_connection& Con) {
  this->Con = Con;
}
```

The assignment in constructor raises this error: **use of deleted function....**

I know this means it's calling constructor of db_connection to create new object of Con. But that's not what I wish to have.

And I can't declare the property 'Con' in class declaration as

```
class child {
  public:
    db_connection& Con;
    ...
```

Because a reference must be initialised or assigned. This is a hard situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, to be able to use a reference you need to *initialize* it. For that you should use a *constructor initializer list*:

```
class child {
    db_connection& Con;

  public:
    child(db_connection& con) : Con(con)
    {}
    ...
};
```

That *initializes* the member variable instead of assigning to it inside the constructor.

Comment: how about passing in 2 or more variables? :Con(Con),Var(Var),...?

Comment: oh i found it, comma separated

Comment: it's still "use of deleted function...": error: use of deleted function ‘mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(const mongocxx::v_noabi::client&)’
       Db_Client(Db_Client_),Request(Request_),Response(Response_)

Comment: @johnlowvale I meant if you use a reference member variable. Updated answer.

Comment: now im facing linking problem, the body (implementation) of the constructor not found

Comment: possibly the body of the constructor is defined in the header file, but i already have that .o file in linking command

Comment: i had to move the body of the constructor to .cpp file to be able to link, putting the body {} directly in .hpp file fails

Comment: @johnlowvale Constructor initializer lists can be used when you implement the constructor in a source file as well. And the problem you now have is different from what you were originally asking about, so it could warrant a new question.

Comment: thks, this is solving my matter

Answer (score 1):

If `child` is allowed to take *ownership* of the connection instance passed to it on construction, then you could use a *move constructor*:

`child(db_connection&& Con_) : Con(std::move(Con_)){}`

which obviates a value copy *and* the potential of a dangling reference. This invalidates the `Con_` passed to the constructor.

Comment: yeah, the variable passing in is public

Comment: In which case this answer is about as useful as a trap door in a canoe. I'll leave it up though as it might be useful in other instances.

Comment: this fact is scary: "This invalidates the Con_ passed to the constructor.". The original owner of the variable can't use this variable any more? seems not able to pass the same Con_ to the second child